# Ignite uses more memory than expected

Tags: caching, ignite

I am using Ignite to build a framework for data calculation. One big problem is the memory usage is a little more than expected. The data using 1G memory outside Ignite will use more than 1.5G in Ignite cache.

I turned off backup and copyOnRead already. I don't use query feature so no extra index space. I also counted in the extra space used for each cache and cache entry. The total memory usages still doesn't add up.

The data value for each cache entry is a big map contains list of primitive arrays. Each entry is about 120MB.

What can be the problem? The data structure or the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite does introduce some overhead to your data and half of a GB doesn't sound too bad too me. I would recommend you to refer to this guide for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/capacity-planning

Comment: I'm curious as to how this happens?  It seems to be not just .5GB overhead but 30-50% overhead that grows as the data does.  (zzz and I are on the same team)

Answer (score 0):

Difference between expected and real memory usage arises from 2 main points:

1. Each entry takes constant overhead consists of objects providing support for processing entries in **distributed computing environment**.

E.g. you can declare integer local variable, it takes 4 bytes in the stack, but it's hard to make the variable long live and accessible from other places of program. So you have to create new Integer object, which consumes at least 16 bytes (300% overhead isn't it?). Going further, if you want to make this object mutable and safely acsessible by multiple threads, you have to create new AtomicReference and store your object inside. Total memory consumption will be at least 32 bytes... and so on. Every time we're extending object functionality, we get additional overhead, there is no other way.

2. Each entry stored inside a cache in a special serialized format. So the actual memory footprint of an entry depends on the format is used. By default Ignite uses BinaryMarshaller to convert an object to the byte array, and this array is stored inside a BinaryObject.

The reason is simple, distributed computing systems continiously exchange entries between nodes, and every entry in cache should be ready to be transferred as a byte array.

Please, read the [article](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/capacity-planning#calculating-memory-usage), it was recently updated. You could estimate entry overhead for small entries by hand, but for big entries you should inspect actual entry stored in the cache as a byte array. Look at the [withKeepBinary](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#withKeepBinary()) method.